# Problema con la fecha al mostrarla en Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

¡Hola! En mi aplicación Angular tengo un formControl que recibe el siguiente valor desde una API. Intento setear este valor en el formulario pero al hacerlo muestra otra fecha.

```
"fconfig": "2018-06-30T03:00:00.000Z"
```

Acá está el formControl

```
siniestroForm = this.fb.group({ ...
fecSiniestro: new FormControl<Date | null>({ value: null, disabled: true }, Validators.required),
..});
```

y lo seteo de la siguiente manera:

```
this.siniestroForm.controls.fecSiniestro.setValue(fconfig);
```

Resulta que cuando el valor se setea Angular muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No he podido dar con la forma en que se muestre correctamente el valor que sería 30-06-2018.
Intente de convertirlo de varias maneras con luxon pero me gano. ¡Espero me puedan ayudar! Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Remueve la Z del final y debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Usa el pipe `DatePipe`, recuerda que los pipes son servicios, por lo tanto los puedes inyectar en tu componente u otros servicios.

```
constructor (private readonly _datePipe: DatePipe) {}

private _getDate(date: string) {
   return this._datePipe.transform(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
}

...
this.siniestroForm.controls.fecSiniestro.setValue(this._getDate(fconfig));
```

Recuerda declarar `DatePipe` en tus providers de tu modulo o componente.

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe